# Tangent parallel to asymptote proof

Tags: calculus, functions, proof-writing, asymptotics

I hope you are all doing well. I am currently struggling with a problem and I would greatly appreciate your help in understanding the concept and learning how to solve similar problems.

The problem is from a TEST BAC in Algeria and the question is as follows:

Prove that the function $C_f$ has a tangent line that is parallel to the asymptote $y = x$ at a certain $x_0$ value, which we need to find.

The given information is as follows:

- $f(\alpha) = \alpha + 1$
- $g(\alpha) = 0$
- $f(x) = \frac{xe^x}{e^x + 1}$
- $f'(x) = \frac{e^x \cdot g(x)}{(e^x + 1)^2}$
- $g(x) = x + 1 + e^x$

$C_f$ represents the graph of function $f(x)$ and $\alpha$ is a solution to $g(x)$

I would like to understand the steps involved in proving the existence of a tangent line for the function $C_f$ that is parallel to the asymptote $y = x$ at a certain $x_0$ value. Additionally, I need guidance on how to determine the value of $x_0$ based on the given information.

Thank you for your assistance in solving this problem and providing insights for similar problems.

Comment: Hi, please enclose your LaTeX in `$...$` to make them render properly. Thanks.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could explain what part of this are you struggling with, rather than asking for a step-by-step solution. For example, have you come across this kind of question before, and if so why can the solution there not be transferred to this setting?

Comment: What is $C_f$ here? What is $g(x)$ here? What is $\alpha$ here? Is your problem equivalent to finding such $x_0$ that $f'(x_0)=1$?

Comment: I'm with Ivan Kaznacheyeu. You talk about the function "$C_f$" but do not bother to define it. $f$ is defined, but "$C_f$" is left without explanation. You proclaim that "we know for sure" that $T = \alpha + 1 + x$. But nowhere else is there any mention of "$T$", so this bit of information is no use at all. You give all sorts of information about $\alpha$ without any mention of what $\alpha$ is. It looks like maybe $\alpha$ is supposed to be where the tangent is taken? But you call that $x_0$ both before and after talking about $\alpha$. This is a mess.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are asking whether $f$ has a tangent line that is parallel to $y=x$,
i.e. has slope $1$.
Then we need to determine if there exists ${x_0}$ such that $f'({x_0})=1$, i.e.
$$
e^{x_0}({x_0}+1+e^{x_0})=(e^{x_0}+1)^2. \tag{1}
$$
Dividing by $e^{x_0}\neq 0$ and simplifying, we have
$$
-{x_0}+e^{-{x_0}}+1=0. \tag{2}
$$
(The converse is also true.) This is reminiscent of the given $g(\alpha)=0$, i.e.
$$
\alpha+e^\alpha+1=0.
$$
If ${x_0}=-\alpha$, then we have $(2)$ and hence $(1)$.
This shows that $f$ indeed has a tagent line with slope $1$
at the point $x_0=-\alpha$.